# Video is loaded several times in HTML

Tags: html, video

I have added a video to my website

```
<video controls style="width:410px;height:225px;">
    <source src="video/video_example.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
</video>
```

Whenever I reload the page, the network section in my Chrome Webdeveloper runs it 3 times.
[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser requests parts of the video in order to figure out if it can play it or not before getting the rest of the file to play.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior and is called streaming.